# Passing data between Collections and Regex.Match method

Tags: c#, .net, regex, blueprism

I am building a BP object that does the following:

1. Captures text from some rows in an Excel file into a Blueprism collection using the standard Excel VBO.
2. Puts that collection's contents through a Regex.Match code stage in order to extract a particular value from each row in the collection.
3. The code stage is then supposed to populate another (output) collection with the extracted values.

Blueprism seems to use c# DataTable objects for collections? I tried using List<> objects, but BP will not implicitly cast those (or anything else for that matter), so guess I have to use DataTable.
The input and output variables in the code below (first and last lines), are the wrappers for the actual BP collections in the BP object.

```
        DataTable localList = input;
        DataTable localOutput = new DataTable();
        DataRow[] rows = localList.Select();


        while (localList != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
            {
                string indexValue = Convert.ToString(localList.Rows[i]);

                //example Regex
                string sPattern1 = "[0-9]{5,8}[A-Z][A-Z]";
                Match match1 = Regex.Match(indexValue, sPattern1);

                ///same thing with sPattern2, 3, 4, 5 & 6... with corresponding match2, 3, etc...


                if (match1.Success || match2.Success || match3.Success || match4.Success ||
                match5.Success || match6.Success)
                {
                    localOutput.NewRow();
                    localOutput.Rows.Add(indexValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    localOutput.NewRow();
                    localOutput.Rows.Add("Not Found");
                }
            }
        }
              output = localOutput.Select();
```

So, this code compiles OK, i.e. doesn't throw any type-cast errors or anything like when I tried to use List<>, but then when I run the object BP throws the following runtime exception:

```
Internal : Could not execute code stage because exception thrown by code stage: Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.
```

What am I doing wrong? I'd appreciate any help with this, thank you.

Comment: You forget to add column to your `localOutput`.  `localOutput.Add("ColumnName", typeof(string))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to define the columns:

```
DataTable localOutput = new DataTable();
localOutput.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof (string));
```

Then you can add new rows.